# Prove $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n^2+2}{3n^3+1}=0$ directly from the definition of limit.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

One of my homework questions is:

> Prove $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n^2+2}{3n^3+1}=0$ directly
>   from the definition of limit.

In trying to follow: [Prove that $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n^2+1}  = 0$ from the definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75429/prove-that-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracnn21-0-from-the-definition) , i have so far:

**Proof:**

It must be shown that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists an integer $N$ such that $\left|\frac{2n^2+2}{3n^3+1}-0\right| <\epsilon$ whenever $n>N$.

$\left|\frac{2n^2+2}{3n^3+1}-0\right|=\frac{2n^2+2}{3n^3+1}>\frac{2n^2}{3n^3}=\frac{2}{3n}$.

Because in the problem im given, the left side of the inequality that im trying to simplify i guess, is instead greater than the right side, im stuck.

And i dont understand the how or why behind the algebraic manipulations that the original author and one of the answers performs, in the linked question:

$$\left|\frac{n}{n^2 + 1}\right| < \epsilon \text{ whenever }x \gt M.$$

$$ n \lt \epsilon(n^2 + 1) $$

$$n \lt  \epsilon n^2 + \epsilon$$

Truly do feel clueless at this point!

Comment: You want to get an *upper* bound, not a lower bound.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given and let $N>\frac{4}{3\epsilon}$. If $n>N$, then $n>\frac{4}{3\epsilon}$ or $$\epsilon>\left|\frac{4}{3n}\right|$$

Thus :

$$\epsilon>\left|\frac{4n^2}{3n^3}\right|$$
$$\epsilon>\left|\frac{2n^2+2n^2}{3n^3}\right|\geq\left|\frac{2n^2+2}{3n^3}\right|>\left|\frac{2n^2+2}{3n^3+1}\right|=\left|\frac{2n^2+2}{3n^3+1}-0\right|$$

Do these manipulations make sense?

Comment: Why $N>\frac{4}{3\epsilon}$, more specifically why $\frac{4}{3}$?